# Compress RSA Encoded value in java

Tags: java, string, utf-8, rsa

I am having a java class in which `RSA Encryption` is performed for the passed `String` value. getting encoded value as lengthy.

Input String: `justin`

RSA Encoded value as output: `.eJwdy00OwiAQBtC7zFqS4Ufg8zLNUIaGDZjaxoXx7ja-_fvQc751X3qlB2Wp4kKCU47BZy4A7pa9uuitqNKN5t63PuToY1vO87-wri02gSlSiwloMKhcDZxoSClDAl-zj9exjHkFy0zfH5pUI3w.YfvMdQ.GcmMQuY3BN33JATAfFB3ZyeXO8U`

RSA Encryption Code:

```
String username="justin";
String encrypteduser=getEncryptedPassword(username);
System.out.println("encrypteduser! " + encrypteduser); 
public String getEncryptedPassword(String plainTextPassword)
    {
        String result="";
        
        try {
            result= getEncryptedPasswd(plainTextPassword);
            log.info("result:   " + result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
    
 protected String getEncryptedPasswd(String plain) throws Exception {
            try {
                InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(getCertificate().getBytes());
                CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
                X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(is);

                PublicKey pubKey = cert.getPublicKey();
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);

                byte cipherBytes[] = cipher.doFinal(plain.getBytes());
                String encrypted = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherBytes);
                return encrypted;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
        
        
        private String getCertificate() {
        
        String certStr = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
                + "MIIGgDCCBWigAwIBAgIKMvrulAAAAARG5DANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBbMRMwEQYK"
                + "CZImiZPyLGQBGRYDbmV0MRkwFwYKCZIm"
                + "-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

        return certStr;
    }
```

and my goal here is that wanna compress RSA Encoded value into shorten one.

I hope after conversion(`RSA` to `UTF-8`) will get some shortened value.

Note: looking for some compression to the Encoded value if `UTF-8` conversion not helps.

Is there any way to achieve this in java 8?

Comment: `result.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`?  Don’t expect it to be shorter, though.  UTF-8 is not a form of compression.

Comment: How about not using base64 in the first place? Just use `cipherBytes`.

Comment: Hi @VGR
Thanks for your response, i'm just looking for something that compress RSA Encoded Value to shorten, Could you please help me on this?

Comment: RSA bytes themselves cannot really be distinguished from random. So at that point no compression is feasible.

Comment: @Holger

Thanks for your suggestion, I hope this line needs to be changed "String encrypted = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherBytes);". right? if yes, kindly share me what kinda change i need to make here?

Comment: This heavily depends on what you actually want to do with the `String`.

Comment: Why do you encrypt with RSA and why this size is not suitable for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remain largely compatible with US-ASCII, a 7 bit character code, UTF-8 only encodes single byte characters using the lower 7 bits as well. That means that the same 95 printable characters are present using a single byte in UTF-8 and ASCII. Moving to two or higher byte UTF-8 encoding takes **more** space, so that's not useful at all.

So basically you can use any text encoding for ASCII  that exists. You are already using base 64 which is already pretty dense. However, you could e.g. also use [Z85](https://rfc.zeromq.org/spec/32/) which can contain more binary data, with the disadvantage that it is not a power of two, so the encoding / decoding (or base conversion) will be somewhat trickier and costly. Furthermore, a base 85 encoding only encodes around 6.41 bits per character over 6 bits for base 64, so the return is minimal (around 6.82%).

You should always indicate the encoding when performing conversion. However,UTF-8 is fully compatible to ASCII for base 64 and Z85 as mentioned before. So I'd indicate encoding `StandardCharsets.US_ASCII`, not `UTF_8` as others no doubt will propose.

Just to be sure: if you are able to handle bytes then *no encoding* is always better than performing some conversion to a less efficient representation.

---

The only real way of creating smaller ciphertext is to look at hybrid encryption. Just encrypting or deriving a symmetric key with RSA and use that to encrypt a small string such as a password is not really feasible. An RSA ciphertext consist of (largely) random bytes, so at least on average is not possible to compress these bytes any further.

However, you could take a look at ECIES, possibly with a *compressed* ephemeral public key. Then you could use 33 bytes for the public key (of e.g. curve type P256, for a 128 bit strength) and a specific maximum password size for the password itself, encrypted with e.g. AES-CTR. You should use a static sized encoding for the passwords, or you could leak the password size.

Comment: Yes, ECIES, and you should add that is not compressible as in your comment.

Comment: Why wouldn't the public key be compressible? The ciphertext wouldn't, but the public key that is used to perform the ECDH key agreement is, right?

Comment: Well, It was for RSA ciphertext. Compression of the public key is fine as in your answer, however, one should already have your public key in some directory, right?

Comment: Yes, the receiver should share a static, trusted public key, just as within RSA. However, with IES, you have to generate another ephemeral key pair at the sender and then attach that public key with the ciphertext.

Comment: Yes, for the ephemeral side from the sender, one has to it.

Answer (score 2):

Your cipher text appears to be already UTF-8–encoded. It's base-64–encoded; base-64 uses only US-ASCII characters, and US-ASCII encoding is a subset of UTF-8 encoding.

I believe you are not asking for what you want. Do you want shorter cipher text? If so, UTF-8 has nothing to do with that.

RSA cipher text has a length equal to the modulus of the RSA key. (This also imposes an upper bound on the plain text length.) The key size is chosen according to security requirements. Nowadays 3072 bits or maybe 2048 bits is typical. With those key lengths, the shortest text encoding generally supported is 512 or 342 characters, respectively. (There are some less common binary-to-text encodings that could get it down to 480 or 320 characters, respectively, but they will cause problems in URLs and other contexts because they use more symbols.)

If you want a shorter cipher text, use a different encryption algorithm. For public key cryptography, elliptic curve algorithms give the same level of security with shorter keys (as far as we know, anyway). This means your plain text and cipher text will be shorter. Or, perhaps a symmetric algorithm might work in your scheme. Depending on the mode, these can output cipher text the same length as the plain text (although that leaks information about the plain text and might compromise security).

Cryptographic operations result in strings bytes that can have any value in any sequence. I'm not aware of any single-byte character encodings that map every value to a character, and there isn't a multi-byte character encoding that maps every byte sequence to a character. Taking these facts together, you'll always require something like base-64 encoding to convert your cipher text to actual characters. So your text will be 33% longer on average.

Comment: iso-latin-1 maps every byte to a character, in a very trivial way.

Comment: @Holger Well, no, officially it does not. But at least the Java encoding maps every character value below 0x100 to a byte with the same value.

Comment: @Holger Aside from the control characters, which would be extremely problematic in most contexts, isn't there [a big gap at 0x7F?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Code_page_layout)

Comment: These are good points, but in the end, I am presuming the OP really needs printable characters, and probably a subset at that, precluding base-85, etc.

Comment: @erickson I’m not saying that every character is printable, but your statement wasn’t referring to printable characters either.

Comment: Yes, that's true, I wasn't very precise.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes it seems you are confusing things here. The first 256 Unicode codepoints map directly to the iso-latin-1 character set. U+007F to U+009F are control characters. This is different from Windows-1252 which has printable characters in the 0x7F to 0x9F range which is not compatible to iso-latin-1 and doesn’t have a simple mapping to Unicode.

Comment: @Holger I didn't know that the "gap" was actually defined with control characters, like the range 0x00 to 0x31. Interesting!

Comment: @Holger Well it is a confusing standard and you are right in that I got confused. But note that although the Unicode code block is called Basic Latin, the ISO 8859-1 (Latin-1) encoding actually  doesn't define these control characters; the are defined in ISO 6429 instead.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes yes, but for the mapping from byte to character, we do not need an actual semantic for the control characters, but just [the nicely defined one to one mapping](https://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/ISO8859/8859-1.TXT). Which is quite useful if someone needs a way to losslessly convert a `byte[]` to a `String` and back, as long as being printable is not a requirement. Especially under Java 9+, when the operation is a no-op (or plain copy operation), as the string will use exactly the same internal representation.

Comment: I'm just saying that it isn't Latin 1, so it may fail if you use that logic to communicate with other systems. I honestly don't know why the OP needs a string; usually strings needs to be printable to be useful. This kind of thing is only useful if you must store it to please a stringly defined internal API.